# Android Button always takes two clicks to fire onClick()

Tags: android, button, onclick, focusable

I have a RelativeLayout inside of a ScrollView that contains a Button and some TextViews and EditTexts.

In my xml layout file, I am defining android:onClick but it always takes two clicks of the button to fire the event.  The button always gets the focus on the first click and fires the onClick event on the second click.  I have tried setting focusable and focusableInTouchMode both to false but the behavior doesn't change.

Here is my layout file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DensityActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
        ...

        <TextView
        ...

        <TextView
        ...

        <EditText
        ...

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_button_calculate"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ad_edit_obs_temp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20pt"
            android:paddingLeft="6pt"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="@string/button_calculate" />

        <TextView
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to why the focusable and focusableInTouchMode don't seem to do anything?

I thought it might be my onClick() method not doing what it should so I reduced it to something simple just to see and it behaves the same.  Here is my simplified onClick():

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Argh").setMessage("Watch out!").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();

}
```

Comment: post your `onClick()`. You shouldn't need `focusable` for the `Button` unless you have something else going on that we don't know about.

Comment: hmm, if I use the same layout in a new project, it works fine.  You are right, there must be something going on that I don't know about.  I will keep investigating.

Comment: You can try to clean your project. "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: d'oh.  I was setting the button to be focusable in code in my onCreate function.  I was using that to hide the keyboard when the activity loaded.  Dumb mistake.  I am new on stack overflow so I cannot answer my own question for 8 hrs.

Comment: You can add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"` to your `Activity` tag in your `manifest` to accomplish that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found it.  It was, of course, my own mistake.
At the end of my onCreate method I was doing this:

```
// Set the focus to the calculate button so the keyboard won't show up automatically 
Button calcButton = (Button)findViewById( R.id.ac_button_calculate );
calcButton.setFocusable( true );
calcButton.setFocusableInTouchMode( true ); 
calcButton.requestFocus();
```

So of course, no matter what I did in my xml file, I was overriding it in my code.
Instead, I used this to hide the keyboard:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN );
```

Which works great.

Comment: Have you tried putting both focusable and focusableInTouchMode on false in the xml or style file? I had this same problem and this solved it for me, no need to do the whole window get thing.